# What is meant by Wordless Groans of the Spirit?

Tags: romans, spirit

We see St Paul writing in Romans 8:26-28 (NIV) that the Spirit intercedes for us through ' wordless groans ' . One is intrigued by the said usage of St Paul who always stood for clarity and simplicity of communication (1 Cor 2:1).

My question therefore,  is : What did St Paul mean by Wordless Groans of the Spirit in Romans 8:26-28 ? Views of scholars of any denomination are welcome.

> Rom 8 - **26** In the same way, the Spirit helps us in our weakness.
> For we do not know how we ought to pray, but the Spirit Himself
> intercedes for us with **groans** too deep for words. **27** And He
> who searches our hearts knows the mind of the Spirit, because the
> Spirit intercedes for the saints according to the will of God.

Comment: You need to learn to ask questions on the appropriate site.

Comment: Thanks, curiousdannii. I was trying to relate Romans 8 with 1 Cor 2, which calls for some interpretation. Hence the Question on CSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the meaning of the "groanings" is in the next word (the last in the Rom 8:26) - ἀλαλήτοις = "unutterable, unspeakable", etc.

That is, the Holy Spirit intercedes on our behalf in a way that beyond what human words can express.

[Personal note:  I have often been in prayer and used this wonderful promise when I could not find words to express my deep feelings, knowing that the Holy Spirit would convey the ideas, "beyond human words" to the throne of grace perfectly.]

Ellicott expresses it this way:

> **With groanings which cannot be uttered**. When the Christian’s prayers are too deep and too intense for words, when they are rather a
> sigh heaved from the heart than any formal utterance, then we may know
> that they are prompted by the Spirit Himself. It is He who is praying
> to God for us.

The Cambridge commentary is similar:

> **which cannot be uttered** i.e. in all the depth of His meaning; which must indeed pass, human words, even when He inspires them. In
> any special case of prayer the saint may or may not use words; but,
> anywise, the root-desires that underlie the prayer, being the Holy
> Spirit’s promptings, are “unutterable” to the full.

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary says this:

> **maketh intercession for us with groanings which cannot be uttered**—that is, which cannot be expressed in articulate language.
> Sublime and affecting ideas, for which we are indebted to this passage
> alone! "As we struggle to express in articulate language the desires
> of our hearts and find that our deepest emotions are the most
> inexpressible, we 'groan' under this felt inability. But not in vain
> are these groanings. For 'the Spirit Himself' is in them, giving to
> the emotions which He Himself has kindled the only language of which
> they are capable; so that though on our part they are the fruit of
> impotence to utter what we feel, they are at the same time the
> intercession of the Spirit Himself in our behalf."

Answer (score 2):

Paul gives the context for this phrase by showing it is about a particular weakness Christians sometimes have when in prayer.  There are times when Christians are at a loss as to how to pray. They are trying to find the right words, but cannot. This clearly is referring to spontaneous, individual prayers to God, not to any chanting of a formulaic prayer, or reading out aloud a prayer printed on a sheet of paper (or on an app. Note to self: try to keep up to speed with technology.)

Here is an explanation of the verses in question from a Christian who died over 300 years ago, but is still relevant today:

> "***1. The help of the Spirit in prayer.***  While we are in this
> world, hoping and waiting for what we see not, we must be praying.
> Hope supposes desire, and that desire offered up to God is prayer; we
> groan.
>
> ***2. Our weakness in prayer.***  ...We are not competent judges of our own condition. We are short-sighted, and very much biased in
> favour of the flesh, and apt to separate the end from the way. *'You
> know not what you ask'.* Mt.20:22... The apostle speaks of this in the
> first person: *'We know not'*. ***If so great a saint as Paul knew not
> what to pray for, what little reason have we to go forth about that
> duty in our own strength?***
>
> ***3.  The assistance which the Spirit gives us in that duty.***  *'He helps our infirmities'* ...The Spirit in the heart helps, dwelling in
> us, working in us, as a Spirit of grace - heaves with us and
> supplication. *Helpeth* - ***'synantilambanetai'*** *heaves with us,
> over against us,* helps as we would help one that lifts up a burden.
> Christ intercedes for us in heaven [Heb.7:25], the Spirit intercedes
> for us in our hearts [Rom.8:27].
>
> Now this intercession which the Spirit makes is (1) *With groanings
> that cannot be uttered.* The strength and fervency of those desires
> which the Holy Spirit works... when there is not a word spoken, as
> Moses prayed (Ex.14:15), and Hannah (1 Sam.1:13). It is not the
> rhetoric and eloquence, but the faith and fervency of our prayers that
> the Spirit works, as an intercessor, in us.
>
> *Cannot be uttered:* they are so confused, the soul is in such a hurry with temptations and troubles, we know not what to say, or how to
> express ourselves. We can but cry, *'Abba, Father'* [Rom.8:15], and
> refer ourselves to him with a holy, humble boldness; this is the work
> of the Spirit." *Matthew Henry's Commentary on the Whole Bible*, p.1771
> columns 1 & 2., Matthew Henry, Hendrickson, Fourth printing, new edition August 2014

Yes, even *"St Paul, who always stood for clarity and simplicity of communication"*, knew that in prayer, human limitations could be reached which only the indwelling Holy Spirit could overcome so as to turn the Cristian's silent, and often anguished heart-cries sensible before the throne of God in heaven. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks, Anne, for the brilliant inputs. Kindly complete your answer by naming the ' Christian who died over 300 years ago' and whom you have quoted .

Comment: @Kadalicatt Joseph Sibichan. I've added an edit showing he was called Matthew Henry (1662-1714). He not only wrote his massive Bible Commentary but was a prolific Protestant preacher, holding pastorates until his death. Baptist preacher Charles H. Spurgeon spoke highly of Henry's mighty commentary.

Comment: Thanks, Anne, for the additional information.